# Issue with boot loader

Tags: c, omap

I am using OMAP3515 processor (Generic CortexA8 Device) for my project and want to boot the system form UART3. 
The boot loader code which I am using is working fine when using emulator i.e it is able to write the image into FLASH.
The same boot loader code when I am sending through UART it is executing in RAM but unable to write the image into FLASH.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to unlock the flash. Some systems provide a option to lock and unlock flash.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , but it is working correctly with emulator, if lock and unlock is the problem then it will not even work with emulator.

Comment: may be emulator has automatic mechanism to unlock it before flashing... just a guess. I have faced similar issues with other system and had to manually unlock flash before flashing through UART. However, I have not used TI Omap based system.